# Jenkins maven project violation report in pipeline project

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to convert jenkins maven project to pipeline project, we have mvn clean install step and next violation plugin can someone help me How to include violation report in pipeline project (check style and findbugs)

[image]

Comment: Question - Is not the Violations Jenkins plugins is Deprecated?
If it's deprecated, I don't think there will be any guide to convert from freestyle to pipeline. I would recommend go away from Violations plugins and use a static code analysis tool like sonarqube and etc..

Answer (score 0):

In [declarative style](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/), using the new [Warnings Next Generation plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/), you would do something like

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        ... pre-conditions & other stuff previously handled by your jenkins maven job ...
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                withMaven {
                    sh 'mvn clean install'
                }
            }
        }
        ... post-conditions previously handled your jenkins maven job ...
    }
    post {
        always {
           recordIssues(
               enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, 
               tools: [java(), checkStyle(pattern: 'checkstyle-result.xml', reportEncoding: 'UTF-8'), findBugs(pattern: 'findbugs.xml')]
           )               
        }
    }
}
```

See the [pipeline documentation page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/) for more details about syntax etc